# Add Name property in every ListBox Item

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, listboxitem

I have an WPF project, in which i have a `Resource Dictionary` where i store my styles. In this dictionary i have a `ListBoxItem Template` that looks like this.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GenreStyle">
    <Grid Width="150" Height="150" Background="Transparent">
        <Image x:Name="GenreImage" Tag="{Binding Genre}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Source="{Binding GenreSource}" Width="140" Height="140" MouseEnter="GenreImage_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="GenreImage_MouseLeave" MouseLeftButtonDown="GenreImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="GenreImage_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now what i want to do is, read the Images `Tag` when i click in each item.
What im doing now is this :

```
private void StationsListLB_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(StationsListLB, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(??????);
    }
}
```

Comment: No comments explaining the downvotes?

Comment: Maybe because there's no question?

Comment: Now what i want to do is, read the Images Tag when i click in each item. There you are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I just had to capture the `System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs`.
And then very simple :

```
private void StationsListLB_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(StationsListLB, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        var opa = e.OriginalSource as System.Windows.Controls.Image;
        MessageBox.Show(opa.Tag.ToString());
    }
}
```